# - and /> in xml document (with php trying to create the same document as in example)

Tags: php, xml

I have example of xml document and with php trying to create the same xml.

This is part of example of xml document (as it appears if open with web browser)

```
-<DeclarationFile>
  -<Declaration Id="DEC">
    -<DokPVNv4>
```

Need to create the same. My php code

```
$DOM = new DOMDocument('1.0','UTF-8');

$root = $DOM->createElement('DeclarationFile');
$DOM->appendChild($root);

$child_declaration_id = $DOM->createElement('Declaration');
$root->appendChild($child_declaration_id);

$child_declaration_id_att = $DOM->createAttribute('Id');
$child_declaration_id->appendChild($child_declaration_id_att);

$att_child_declaration_id_text = $DOM->createTextNode('DEC');
$child_declaration_id_att->appendChild($att_child_declaration_id_text);

$DokPVNv4 = $DOM->createElement('DokPVNv4');
$root->appendChild($DokPVNv4);
```

In output (web browser) get this

```
-<DeclarationFile>
  <Declaration Id="DEC"/>
  <DokPVNv4/>
 </DeclarationFile>
```

1. In example of xml there are `-` before `<Declaration Id="DEC">` and `<DokPVNv4>`. With my php code do not have. What means these `-` and how to create them with php?
2. In example of xml in `<Declaration Id="DEC">` and `<DokPVNv4>` there are no `/`. With my code I get `/`. How to remove them (and what these `/` mean)?

I suppose all differences are related with root element?

Update. What understand at the moment from answers: if for some element/tag has no closing tag, then element ends with `/`. And `-` `+`, yes, browser creates them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code creates elements with wrong nesting.
Try change this

```
$root->appendChild($DokPVNv4);
```

to this

```
 $child_declaration_id->appendChild($DokPVNv4);
```

Comment: Corrected. And now ok with `<Declaration Id="DEC">`. But for `<DokPVNv4/>` have `/`. What see, when made corrections, then for `<Declaration Id="DEC">` get closing `</Declaration>`. For `<DokPVNv4/>` has no closing tag

Comment: Try posting original XML you are trying to copy. The code creates an empty element which is serialized without closing part just using />

Comment: .... it has 181 rows... would not good if I post so long... Seems have got answers to my question. I mark your answer as accepted, because showed my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

That `-` is probably the browser drawing in a `+`/`-` button that allows you to open/close those elements. The `/>` is **REQUIRED** by the XML specifications. Either tags are containers, e.g.

```
<foo>
   ...
</foo>
```

Or they are a singleton tag, in which case they must be self-closing, e.g.

```
<bar />
```

Your code doesn't explicitly add them, but since they are REQUIRED in xml, the DOM system is adding them for you.

Comment: Yes, now see that `+` and `-` browser adds.